# Swipe gesture recognizer in slidebar

Tags: java, android, slide

I have this activity for slidebar

```
public class EventiPromozioniActivity extends FragmentActivity{

List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
List<String> fragmentTitles = new Vector<String>();
// page adapter between fragment list and view pager
private SlidePagerAdapter mSlidePagerAdapter;
// view pager
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_slide_bar_ricerche);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
       //
    }

        // creating fragments and adding to list
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, First.class.getName()));
    fragmentTitles.add("FIRST");

    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Second.class.getName()));
    fragmentTitles.add("SECOND");

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    View pagerStrip = findViewById(R.id.pagerTabStrip);
    if (pagerStrip instanceof PagerTabStrip) {
        PagerTabStrip pagerTabStrip = (PagerTabStrip) pagerStrip;
        pagerTabStrip.setDrawFullUnderline(true);
        pagerTabStrip.setTabIndicatorColorResource(android.R.color.black);
        // pagerTabStrip.setTextColor(color.white);
    } else if (pagerStrip instanceof PagerTitleStrip) {
        PagerTitleStrip pagerTitleStrip = (PagerTitleStrip) pagerStrip;
        pagerTitleStrip.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));//TODO: deprecato
    }

    this.mSlidePagerAdapter = new SlidePagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments, fragmentTitles);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(this.mSlidePagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);

}

}
```

how can I recognize when page slides? I want to invoke a method inside a fragment when the page slide.

I really appreciate any help you can provide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
  mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float arg1, int arg2) {
         // Check the page is slide And do your stufff
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int position) {
        }
    });
```